# Python list return statement deciphering

Tags: python, list, syntax, for-loop

I have the following statement in a python routine:

```
return [hulls[h][i] for h, i in hull]
```

And I can't figure out what it does actually return.

I mean, hulls is a list of hull, so 'hulls[n]' is of type 'hull'. Additionally, <strike>hull is of type 'Point'</strike> hull is a list of points, but

```
for h, i in hull?
```

The docs don't mention why and how you can perform such a call, and it smells like some sort of list comprehension call, but I still can't read that syntax properly.

So I'd like help in understanding how you can translate the sentence in pseudocode, or c#

Thanks a lot.

Comment: "hull is of type 'Point'" - no, it isn't, assuming the code actually works as written. It's a sequence of points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is list comprehension. Your return statement could be rewritten less compactly as:

```
result = []
for h, i in hull:
    result.append(hulls[h][i])
return result
```

Comment: Thanks! One more thing though: the 'for h, i' mean that BOTH counters increase at the same time, or something else?

Comment: `[i*j for i,j in [(1,2), (3,4), (5,6)]]` returns `[2 (which is 1*2), 12  (which is 3*4), 30 (which is 5*6)]`. Basically, `for i,j in blah` means iterate over the items in blah, and unpack each one onto i,j. What does the variable `hull` represent? It should be a list of tuples, or lists, or something else that can be unpacked into two items.

Answer (score 1):

Hulls looks to be a two dimensional array of things. Hull is a list of pairs of ints (x,y). For each coordinate in Hull, it returns the item in hulls in that place.

Comment: The h,I unpacked the Tupperware and assigns the first item to h and the second to I.

Comment: Thanks. Your reply and David's completely cleared my doubts, yet I must accept David's for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, David is correct. If you're still confused about the line 
        for h, i in hull:
I think it means that hull is a list of tuples that have multiple elements. So you're using every element in hull to use as indices for hulls.